# Insert value in place holders using windows batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i have a line

```
Removing,policy,NULL,from,group,NULL
```

i want to insert abc at first NULL and xyz at second NULL. 
I am banging my head since morning and still cant figure out how to do it. Can someone suggest something ?

Comment: More information needed. Is the line in a variable? or a text file? Why do you want to do this? (what is the ultimate goal?) Do you have control over the initial preparation of the line with NULLs?

Comment: there can be any number of strings before NULL. yes i have control over preparation of line. line is a variable @dbenham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over the format of the place holders, then I recommend using delayed expansion variables instead. You can then use a FOR /F loop to do the substitutions, because delayed expansion occurs after FOR variable expansion.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: Define the line with variable place holders
:: Quoted ! literal must be escaped as ^! when delayed expansion is enabled
set "var=Removing,policy,^!val1^!,from,group,^!val2^!"

:: Show the starting value
echo var=!var!

:: Define the replacement values
set "val1=abc"
set "val2=xyz"

:: Perform the substitution
for /f "delims=" %%A in ("!var!") do set "var=%%A"

:: Show the result
echo var=!var!
```

The reason I use delayed expansion to transfer the value to a FOR variable instead of simply using `%var%` without FOR is to handle the possibility of poison characters like `|`, `<`, etc. within the text, possibly with or without quotes. The delayed expansion and FOR variable make it so I don't have to worry about escaping or quoting the content. The only two exceptions are `^` and `!` literals that might be present. The easiest way to preserve them is to also encode them as delayed expansion variables.

Comment: The `for /f` is not required to perform the substitution; a simple `set "var=%var%"` do it.

Comment: @Aacini - That is true for the example text, but not generally true. Using normal variable expansion can fail if there are a mixture of poison characters and quotes. The FOR /F solution can be made to work with all characters, with some extra work to handle `^` and `!` literals, if necessary.

Comment: You are right, but I wrote my comment based on the description given in [your original post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29923252/revisions), where you mentioned nothing about "poison characters".

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how the line is acquired so I'll use it directly:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set  "line=Removing,policy,NULL,from,group,NULL"
for /f "tokens=1-6 delims=," %%a in ("%line%") do (
    set "new_line=%%a,%%b,abc,%%d,%%e,xyz"
)
echo !new_line!
```

You'll need delayed expansion if this is taken in another `FOR` loop as I suspect this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

This method assume no previous knowledge of the format/position of the values to be replaced in the input line:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the replacement values
set insert[1]=abc
set insert[2]=xyz

set "line=Removing,policy,NULL,from,group,NULL"

echo Before: %line%
set i=0
set "out="
for %%a in (%line%) do (
   if %%a equ NULL (
      set /A i+=1
      for %%i in (!i!) do set "out=!out!,!insert[%%i]!"
   ) else (
      set "out=!out!,%%a"
   )
)
set "line=%out:~1%"

echo After:  %line%
```

If the line is generated inside a FOR loop, just expand it via delayed expansion in `for %%a in (!line!) do (` command.